# What is mentioned in Valmiki's Ramayan regarding Hanuman's Brahmacharya?

Tags: hanuman, valmiki, brahmacharya, ramayana

As far as I remember it isn't mentioned anywhere in Valmiki's Ramayan. In certain South East Asian texts (as I'm told) Hanuman isn't shown as a Brahmachari.

Comment: The question in the title is one but the question in the body is something else. Here its recommended that we focus on one question at a time. So kindly edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Done. @Rickross

Comment: Thanks. That's a good edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in Valmiki Ramayana , there is nothing about his marriage , however in Parashara Samhita (not to be confused with Parashara Smriti) , it is mentioned  that Lord Hanuman did marry .

http://www.jayahanumanji.com/?p=2226 see shloka no. 8-9

And do remember it was spiritual marriage , not physical marriage like that of humans